# Javascript scoping change

Tags: javascript

I read a lot about javascript scoping but still can't seem to understand why this code (this line the left arrow points to) changing `geval` scope to be the global scope and not the function scope. `geval` is invoked inside `test2` so I thought it would have the same scope..

```
const test2 = () => {
  var x = 2, y = 4;
  console.log(eval('x + y'));  // Direct call, uses local scope, result is 6
  var geval = eval; // equivalent to calling eval in the global scope
  console.log(geval('x + y')); // Indirect call, uses global scope, throws ReferenceError because `x` is undefined
  (0, eval)('x + y'); // another example of Indirect call
}
```

Comment: You could just copy and paste that code into the question instead of adding an image of it.

Comment: Eval has some weird behaviour ( in this case too). The best answer is probably: don't use it at all. And making references to it makes no sense to me too

Comment: evil eval is evil.

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? "Because the spec says it should work that way" would be a possibly answer.

Comment: - Edit to Inline code as snippet

Comment: so many unuseful comments guys...
@Ivar , did you just wanted to complain or also help with an answer?

Comment: @Quentin , no it doesn't! read the code again if you didn't understand.

Comment: @Roy — You accepted an answer which boils down to "Because the spec says it should work that way"

Comment: @Roy [There are a lot of reasons why images of code should not be used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). The fact that I point that out does not mean that I know the answer. But it does help the people who do, or want to copy/paste it to try it their selves, which in the end also helps you to get an answer. Revenge down-voting is not really appreciated. If you simply would've mentioned that you added the code, I would've been glad to undo my down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following excerpts are taken from ECMA-262 7th edition (ECMAScript 2016) –  section numbers sometimes differ between versions.

> 18.2.1.1 Runtime Semantics: PerformEval( x, evalRealm, strictCaller, direct)
>   
>   
>   ...

> 9. If direct is true, then
>
> > a. Let lexEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(ctx's LexicalEnvironment).
> >
> > b. Let varEnv be ctx's VariableEnvironment.

> 10. Else,
>
> > a. Let lexEnv be NewDeclarativeEnvironment(evalRealm.[[GlobalEnv]]).
> >
> > b. Let varEnv be evalRealm.[[GlobalEnv]].

So for an indirect call (not calling **`eval`** by name) you arrive at step 10 which calls  `NewDeclarativeEnvironment(E)` with the global environment record as parameter value.

`NewDeclarativeEnvironment` is described in section 8.1.2.2. As expected this creates an environment record for any variables defined using `let` within script parsed by `eval`, and sets the "**outer lexical environment reference**" of that record to the environment record provided as argument.

Step 10.b sets the variable environment record, for named functions and variables declared with `var`, to the global environment record of the realm `eval` was called in – meaning `window` in a browser document.

In short, calling `eval` indirectly creates a separate environment record for `let` variables declared within the code being evaluated, whose next outer scope (lexical reference) is the global object, but uses the global object for `var` and named function declarations.

If you want to have evaluated code inherit the scope of surrounding code, make a direct call using the name `eval` as the function reference.

The presence of both 9.a and 10.a means that variables declared with `let` are not retained after a call to `eval` no matter what the type of call..

---

**The Historical Why** (edit)

The behavior of indirect calls is likely the result of deprecating calling `eval` on an object and removing the `eval` property from `Object.prototype`.

From the JavaScript 1.2 reference for Object data type methods:

> eval          Evaluates a string of JavaScript code in the context of the specified object.

and calling `eval` on an object in such early versions of JavaScript would result in code evaluation as if it were inside a `with (object) {}` statement.

The rules for indirect calls replace this behavior with a standard response: if an object method is set to `eval` the previous behavior of `object.eval` is not recreated and the scope of evaluated code is the global object exceot for `let` variables. This is similar to the way creating a function from text with `new Function` behaves as if it were defined in global scope. It also has the effect that the `this` value seen by indirect calls to `eval` is the global object (`this` values reside in environmental records).