# Is it possible to define a global constant from within a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, constants

I would like to be able to define a constant that is in the global scope from within a function. With a normal variable this would be possible by defining it outside the function and setting its' value from within the function as shown below:

```
var carType; 

function carType(){

    carType = 'Reliant Robin';

}
```

However you cannot define global variables without setting a value so this would not work with a constant, is there any way around this?

Comment: You might set a non-configurable property on the global object, but it's still a code smell.

Comment: `const carType;` is illegal syntax.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I know, "However you cannot define global variables without setting a value so the program will fail on the first line". I'm asking if there is any way around this

Comment: You can define global variables without setting a value though. `var carType;`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts "I would like to be able to define a constant"

Comment: If you declare a variable before defining it, by definition it is not a constant, so your request makes no sense.

Comment: The question is whether It is possible to define a global constant from within a function and the example code was to show how you might do it if it were a normal variable "With a normal variable this would be possible...". I know it's not possible to do that with a constant, thats why I'm asking the question, I would like to know if there is any way to define a constant that is accessible from the global scope while inside a function

Comment: The short answer is no - you can't create a global _const_, _let_, or _class_ identifier in global scope using declarations within a function or by using `eval`. I looked into the eval case for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116701/5217142) regarding scope.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the point of my comment. Defining a global from within a function is possible, and you can even make it non-writable and non-configurable, but because you are defining it from within a function, it doesn't even make sense to call it a constant.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I see what you are saying, the reason I would like to use it in this case is in a function which is only run once and configures a lot of the functions I use (which I would like to be constants). I define these functions within another function so I can put all the functions out of the way but have them available to execute at the right point in the code.

Comment: You should load your constants in a module and `require()` or `import` the module everywhere the constants need to be referenced.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I would usually do this but in this instance they represent the bulk of my code so I define them after they are called in order for the main code to be easily visible at the top of the file. The script would only be a few lines if I included these from another file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is "yes", but it is not a typical declaration, see the code snippet below

```js
function carType(){
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'carType', {
    value: 'Reliant Robin',
    configurable: false,
    writable: false
  });
}

carType();
carType = 'This is ignored'
console.log(carType);
```